# USE a module2 in SUBROUTINE which is contained in module1 or in module1 itself?

Tags: module, nested, fortran, contains, subroutine

Are there significant differences between a module like the following

```
MODULE module1
   USE module2
   IMPLICIT NONE
       :
CONTAINS

   SUBROUTINE subroutine1
      IMPLICIT NONE
          :
   END SUBROUTINE subroutine1

   SUBROUTINE subroutine2
      IMPLICIT NONE
          :
   END SUBROUTINE subroutine2

END MODULE module1
```

and another one like the following

```
MODULE module1
   IMPLICIT NONE
       :
CONTAINS

   SUBROUTINE subroutine1
      USE module2
      IMPLICIT NONE
          :
   END SUBROUTINE subroutine1

   SUBROUTINE subroutine2
      IMPLICIT NONE
          :
   END SUBROUTINE subroutine2

END MODULE module1
```

apart from the fact that in the first case both the subroutines see the module2?

Comment: Also keep in mind that once you have at the module level `implicit none`, there is no need to also replicate the `implicit none` at the subroutine level. Everything contained within your module will automatically be `implicit none` if your module is declared to be so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference that can be significant and which one should be aware of is that in

```
MODULE module1
   USE module2
```

the `module1` will by default export also all public symbols of `module2`. That won't happen when you use `module2` in a subroutine only, because the module does not see it.

So:

```
  module module2
    integer int
  end module

  module module1
    use module2
  end module

    use module1
    print *, int
  end
```

is possible, but

```
  module module2
    integer int
  end module

  module module1
  contains
    subroutine s
      use module2
    end subroutine
  end module

    use module1
    print *, int
  end
```

is not.

Of course, this behaviour may be controlled in finer details by the `only` clause and by the `private` and `public` statements.